# Function to compute R^2 value for Generalized Linear Model in Julia

Tags: julia, linear-regression, glm

I have a dataset `df` and I need to calculate it's glm summary.

I got everything working properly using

`jlm=glm(@formula(y~x1+x2),df,Normal())`

This gets me the Beta Values and Standard-Error, but I need to find the R2 value too,
if `jlm` was an `lm` model using `r2(jlm)` would've worked fine, but in the Generalized Linear Model, GLM shows there no method r2 for glm.

Is there a way to calculate R2 for glm?

Comment: The support is currently not implemented (AFAICT the same is in R). You need to implement the definition of R^2 would you want to use manually. If you say which definition of R^2 you want calculated I can help you with the code. But if you just need R^2 for `lm` then - as you noted - you can just use `lm` instead of `glm`.

Comment: Thanks @BogumiłKamiński but I found a workaround for the data using ```lm```.

Comment: see also https://discourse.julialang.org/t/pseudo-r2-in-probit/1812 for GLM with probit.